# Java 7 and Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I have a PC with following specs

Windows XP SP3 
Intel Core 2 Duo T6600 2.20 GHZ processor
RAM = 3GB

For android I have
Java 7 SDK Update 1 (1.7.0_01-b08)
Latest SDK Manager etc

I have created two virtual machines for Android 2.3.3 and 4.0 and Bothy of these machines don't load. When I start the AVD it goes to stage where it shows android logo but stays there for hours.

**Is it a problem with Java 7.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Android emulator for Android 2.1 works well with Java 1.7.0_01-b08 on CentOS6.0. Android SDK Manager is the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is/isn't a problem with Java 7, but based on the req. for the SDK found [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html), I wouldn't expect it to work.  It is not one of the supported java JDK's.